# MS Teams Bot SSO Dialog not working clicking continue does nothing

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm currently following the teams toolkit [sample for sso-bot](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2.3.0/bot-sso), its working fine when i use that sample. I tried to follow what they did in it,
if i grant the admin consent, the command work fine since it doesnt need to show that auth window (i'm assuming this), however if i revoke the admin consent it will ask additional permission,

[image]

and when i click continue i expect to get this window (in this pict i grab it when i debug the beginDialog method) [image]

however when i debug the ssoDialog, it pass the beginDialog and sendOAuthCardAsync i can see that it send activity just fine. however nothing happens, here is the card
[image]
and here is the context shown:
[image]

For some reason it stuck there, the waterfall dialog wont move to the next step either, clicking continue just did nothing.

```
export class SSODialog extends ComponentDialog {
  private requiredScopes: string[] = ["User.Read"];
  private dedupStorage: Storage;
  private dedupStorageKeys: string[];
  private SSOCommandMap: Map<string, any>;

  // Developer controlls the lifecycle of credential provider, as well as the cache in it.
  // In this sample the provider is shared in all conversations
  constructor(dedupStorage: Storage) {
    super(DIALOG_NAME);

    const initialLoginEndpoint = `https://${config.botDomain}/auth-start.html`;

    // moved this part here to be able to have the command ready upon membersAdded
    this.SSOCommandMap = new Map(
      SSOCommands.map((command) => [command.commandMessage, command.operationWithSSOToken])
    );
    
    const dialog = new TeamsBotSsoPrompt(
      oboAuthConfig,
      initialLoginEndpoint,
      TEAMS_SSO_PROMPT_ID,
      {
        scopes: this.requiredScopes,
        endOnInvalidMessage: true,
      }
    );
    this.addDialog(dialog);
    this.addDialog(
      new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
        this.ssoStep.bind(this),
        this.dedupStep.bind(this),
        this.executeOperationWithSSO.bind(this),
      ])
    );

    this.initialDialogId = MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    this.dedupStorage = dedupStorage;
    this.dedupStorageKeys = [];
    
     async ssoStep(stepContext: any) {
        const turnContext = stepContext.context as TurnContext;
        stepContext.options.commandMessage = 
        this.getActivityText(turnContext.activity);
        return await stepContext.beginDialog(TEAMS_SSO_PROMPT_ID); <----- its stuck until this point so i tried to debug inside it which shown in the screenshot
     }
  }
```

Can someone point me something that i can debug or so that i can trace the issue, any insight will be of help for me, and feel free to ask me about the code (not sure which one i should provide, most of them still have the same thing from the sample)

when i inspect the devtools on ms teams on web app, i can see this error, it tried to invoke my bot but failed https://teams.microsoft.com/api/chatsvc/apac/v1/agents/28:256d2663-3d03-483b-b690-e93215141254/invoke

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please follow the document to debug the app-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/debug-local?tabs=Windows&pivots=visual-studio-code-v5

Comment: Hi @Sayali-MSFT, i know how to debug, in fact in my question i show screenshot where i debug my code, i just frustrated when it begin the dialog its just stuck there, when i click continue, nothing happened, no error either in the console, only that error on the devtools i shown

Comment: Ensure that you've signed in to Microsoft 365 and that you can toggle breakpoints on the source codes of tabs, bots, message extensions, and Azure Functions.
Remember, the debugging feature is only available for desktop and Android clients after the Developer Preview has been enabled. You can enable it by following the instructions here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro
.